# Fuzzy query on dates with ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform the following query through ElasticSearch Java API

```
{
 "query" : {
    "fuzzy" : {
        "dateOfBirth" : {
            "value" : "1944-11-30",
            "fuzziness" : "365d"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I doesn't understand how to specify the fuzzines value for 365 days in this kind of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
FuzzyQueryBuilder queryBuilder = fuzzyQuery("dateOfBirth" ,"1944-11-30" ).fuzziness(Fuzziness.build("365d"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank's for your help. I've notice that the Fuzziness constructor is private, so I used the static build method provided by the Fuzziness class.

Comment: Ohh I did not notice. Yes you should use build Method . Updated my answer